# Oracle: get part string from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string from oracle table like this:

```
 SELECT col1 FROM MyTable;
 col1
 part1;part2;part3
 ....
```

How can I get a substring from col1 such as part2?

```
 SELECT col1, INSTR(col1, ';', 1, ...) SubStrPart2 // string func?
 col1       SubStrPart2
 ....       part2
```

Not sure what string functions I can use here so that I can easily update it to get a specific sub-string part out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split out on semi-colons, you could try something like this:

```
select col1
     , regexp_substr(col1, '^[^;]') as part1
     , replace(regexp_substr(col1, ';[^;]+;'), ';') as part2
     , replace(regexp_substr(col1, ';[^;]+$'), ';') as part3
```

The replace function removes any occurence of the second parameter if third parameter is not given.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "slice" of col1 between the first and second occurrence of ';', excluded, then the right approach shoule be something like...:

```
select substr(col1, 
              instr(col1, ';', 1, 1)+1,
              instr(col1, ';', 1, 2)-instr(col1, ';', 1, 1)-1)
```

it's a bit complicated because you need to specify the first character to take and then the number of characters to take (and there might be an off-by-one here, needs checking, but I do believe those +1 and -1 are correct).

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good reference](http://www.psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html) about those functions.

```
SELECT col1, SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, ';', 1, ...)) SubStrPart2 // string func?
 col1       SubStrPart2
 ....       part2
```

You could also work with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE WHEN INSTR(col1, ';', 1, ...) > 0
            THEN SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, ';', 1, ...))
            ELSE 'Other value'
       END AS SubStrPart2
...
```

See also [these examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Char-Functions/CombineINSTRandSUBSTRtogether.htm).